# Filtering indexes from dataset in python

Tags: numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I have a dataset with shape (2000,74,64). How to filter indexes 2,4,12,14,22,24 from 2nd dimension(from 74). How can I do it by using for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = np.array(...) # your array (2000, 74, 64)
b = np.zeros((2000, 6, 64)) # new array shape
j = 0 # iterator

for i in range (0, a.shape[1]):
   if i in {2,4,12,14,22,24}:
      b[:,j,:] = a[:,i,:]
      j += 1
```